# Python - dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to programming and python and I dont know how to solve this problem.

```
 my_dict  = {'tiger': ['claws', 'sharp teeth', 'four legs', 'stripes'],
       'elephant': ['trunk', 'four legs', 'big ears', 'gray skin'],
       'human': ['two legs', 'funny looking ears', 'a sense of humor']
       }

new_dict = {}

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    new_v = v + "WOW"
    new_dict[k] = new_v

print(new_dict)
```

I want to make a new dictionary with added phrase but I got an error "can only concatenate list (not "str") to list", but when I am using only one value per key the programme works. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: try `new_v = v + ["WOW"]` which is adding two python `list`

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate a list to another list as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_dict  = {'tiger': ['claws', 'sharp teeth', 'four legs', 'stripes'],
       'elephant': ['trunk', 'four legs', 'big ears', 'gray skin'],
       'human': ['two legs', 'funny looking ears', 'a sense of humor']
       }

    new_dict = {}
    
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        new_v = v + ["WOW"]
        new_dict[k] = new_v
    
    print(new_dict)
```

> {'tiger': ['claws', 'sharp teeth', 'four legs', 'stripes', 'WOW'], 'elephant': ['trunk', 'four legs', 'big ears', 'gray skin', 'WOW'], 'human': ['two legs', 'funny looking ears', 'a sense of humor', 'WOW']}

Answer (score 0):

With list, you only can concatenate a list only.

```
#So here you're trying to concatenate a list with the string
my_dict['tiger'] + 'WOW' # this won't work as one is string and other is List.
my_dict['tiger'] + ['WOW'] # this will work as both are of same type and concatenation will happen.
```